# Convergence of stationary distributions of a sequence of Markov Chains

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I fairly new in the field of Stochastic Processes and Markov Chains so excuse my ignorance.

My question is: If we have a sequence of Markov chains such that each one has a stationary distribution $\pi^{(n)}$ and the chains converge in some way to another Markov chain that has stationary distribution $\pi$, can we say that the $\pi^{(n)}$'s converge to $\pi$ (in some way)?

More precisely:
Let $G$ be a simple (ie no loops or multiple edges), finite, connected graph. Suppose that we have a sequence of Markov chains over $G$. Let $\boldsymbol{P}_1, \boldsymbol{P}_2, \dots$ denote the corresponding transition matrices. Assume that all chains have a stationary distribution (for example, this can be guaranteed when the weights on each edge are positive since $G$ is connected), call them $\pi^{(n)}$. Now say that $\boldsymbol{P}_n\to\boldsymbol{P}$ in some way (for example, let's say that we have entry-wise almost sure convergence, or $\|\boldsymbol{P}_n-\boldsymbol{P}\|\to 0$ for some matrix norm). Suppose that $\boldsymbol{P}$ is a stochastic matrix with stationary distribution $\pi$. Then can we say that $\pi^{(n)}\to\pi$ in some way (similar to the way that the matrices converge)?

My feeling is that there should exist such theorems (maybe with some stronger assumptions). I tried to find such results but I was not successful. Can someone give a reference about such results?

Comment: I think your question has been answered here for symmetric matrices. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436679/eigenvector-convergence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We assume that the Markov chains are on a finite state space, that $P_n \to P$ pointwise, and the limit matrix  $P$ is irreducible, so its stationary measure $\pi$ is unique. Let $\pi^{(n_k)} \to \mu$ be a convergent subsequence of $\pi^{(n)}$.  Then $\pi^{(n_k)}P_{n_k}=\pi^{(n_k)}$, so continuity of multiplication implies that $\mu P=\mu$. Thus $\mu=\pi$. Since this holds for every convergent subsequence and the simplex of probability vectors is compact, we conclude that $\pi^{(n)} \to \pi$.

Answer (score 2):

First $\pi_nP_n^t = \pi_n$ for all $n,t$. Since for the limiting matrix $P$
the distance to stationarity $d(t) = \sup_\mu \|\mu P^t - \pi\|_{TV}$ converges to 0 as $t\to+\infty$,
there exists $t_0$ such that $d(t_0)\le \epsilon$. Then

\begin{align}
\|\pi-\pi_n\|_{TV}
&\le
\|\pi - \pi_nP^{t_0}\|_{TV}
+ \|\pi_n P^{t_0} - \pi_n P_n^{t_0}\|_{TV}
\\&\le \epsilon+ \sup_\mu \|\mu(P^{t_0}-P_n^{t_0})\|\|_{TV}.
\end{align}
Finally
$\sup_\mu \|\mu(P^{t_0}-P_n^{t_0})\|_{TV}\to 0$ as $n\to+\infty$ for a fixed $t_0$ if you assume that $P_n\to P$ entrywise.

Comment: Why does $\mu P^t$ converge to $\pi$ as $t \to \infty$? I think $P$ wasn't assumed to be aperiodic. (But probably one can replace the transition matrices $P^t$ with their Cesàro means to make the argument also work in the case where $P$ is not aperiodic).

Comment: @Jochen Glueck  Alternatively you can replace $P$ with the lazy chain  $(P+I)/2$ and similarly for $P_n$.

Comment: Nice proof! Unlike the (slightly shorter) proof via compactness, this proof has the advantage of potentially giving a rate of convergence by optimizing $t_0(\epsilon)$.